# Relative line number doesn't always work in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xvim

Until recently relative line number worked perfectly in Xcode 13.

I created a `.xvimrc` at `~/Users/username` like I would normally do for vim and wrote `set relativenumber` in it. Saved everything and relative line number worked very well. Recently it started to not work at all unless I hit the escape key and then if I hit any other key it goes back to absolute line number. I haven't changed anything to the xvimrc.

I've tried to reload the xvimrc, I've tried to rebuild/clean the project, I've restarted my mac, etc. Nothing worked...

**P.S: I'm using Xvim2 plugging and not Vim mode.**